# PHP Date() timestamp calculation error

Tags: php, date, timestamp, runtime-error

I have this code :

```
echo date('Y-m-d',1445810400);
```

and it returns the date 2015-10-25 but it is wrong!

The real correct date is the 26th of December 2016, not anymore the 25th.
To solve this bug i have to add 3600 seconds (1h) to the timestamp value.

Is it a date() bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue.

Comment: it seems to happen only with that date, well... not that I have checked every date on the calendar.

Comment: On my system, if I do `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1445810400);`, I get `2015-10-25 22:00:00`. You can check the time with your other timestamps, but I'd suggest adjusting your timezone before you echo your date. You may need to play with it to find the right one.

Comment: Are you sure the dates in your question are right? Are you saying it's off by a year and two months?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what country (or timezone) you're in, but in the UK the 25th of October was the day of a daylight-savings change.

Comment: i have echoed 4 different timestamps : 

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1445637600);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1445724000);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1445810400)';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1445896800)';

and I get these results : 

2015-10-24 00:00:00 , 2015-10-25 00:00:00 , 2015-10-25 23:00:00 , 2015-10-26 23:00:00

. What has happened to the  25th of October 2015 ? 1 more hour to the day?

Comment: *What has happened to the 25th of October 2015 ? 1 more hour to the day?* Yes, exactly that.

Comment: wow! I really didn't know that day had 1 more hour... I'm sorry for my ignorance but do this happen often and on what basis?

Comment: [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) means that in many countries, they go back one hour in the fall, and jump ahead one hour in the spring. The dates can vary from country to country.

Comment: oh, so that is the reason. This means I have checked the day with the clock moved forward 1 hour. At this point the right solution for me is to always add 43200 to the timestamp in order to get 100% safely the right day of the year for every year and month I'm checking on my PHP calendar. Thank you for your help, your answer has solved my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `php.ini` what is the default timezone you have set for it. By default php.ini setting is UTC. Set to your timezone, and restart your web server. You should able to get the correct result. This one is by global.

Another way is in your php file, set the timezone by project. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Here is your input data with this https://www.epochconverter.com/ screenshot:
[image]